# Why is Top-lane Ezreal considered unviable?

Tags: league-of-legends

I want to ask whether you think toplane Ezreal could be viable or not. I thought of it because I want to main a champ I really can play everywhere (except support because I hate this role).

He would be viable as ADC, Mid and I saw him in the jungle too. The reason I ask this question is, because I main toplane. But in case I have to play another lane I at least want to play this champ perfect. I would play him always blue-build.

Advantages:

- can poke out melee champs with his range in lane and deny farm
- can escape ganks easely
- got an global ult and can help the team out or simply depush or push lanes
- if played with blue build he can be the master of kiting and pretty annoying for the enemy bruiser
- for my situation he is pretty cool because he is viable bot, mid and jungle lane
- can be a pretty good tankmelter when played with botrk
- personal playstyle skill and kiting abilities can make this champ highly overpowered
- doesn't need a map

Disadvantages:

- lack of tankyness
- not melee, so their might be a missing frontline
- once the lane is lost hard there is not a good chance to be useful, champs with tanky basestats or abilities prevent that

So I'm asking beacuse I would like to know advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: "I just want some opinions and advantages and disadvantages of you guys" We are not well know for "discussions" ... Go to the [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) when you reach some reputation.

Comment: I've tried to cut out the opinions part to focus on the viability & advantages/disadvantages etc.

Comment: Teeemo is your champ. Any lane or role will be nice with. Teemo currently is best used in TOP, in lower ranks he is the king of MID, it's naturally an ADC, can be used as great support with built in "wards" and is a decent jungler too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an answer whether or not he is viable for the masses the answer is **NO**.

Ezreal is most commonly used as an ADC either bot or mid. Jungling and top works for him but it isn't viable. Of course you can reach challenger with every champion on every lane if you play well but usually Ez has a few weaknesses especially with the current meta.

The current Meta consists of:

- Bruiser/Tank Top
- Bruiser Jungle (few exceptions like Kha'Zix)
- Assassin/AP Mid
- AD Carry
- Support

Now as you already mentioned one of the biggest problems is the missing frontline. However those are some other Issues:

- Tanky masteries are making it more easy for bruisers to lane against him
- Ezreal himself doesn't scale well vs tanks
- You are squishy: You get countered by champions with high base damage.
- While you might have a small advantage for the first 5 levels, there will be a point where you won't deal any damage to the enemy (or you get oneshotted if it's something like Talon/Kha'Zix)
- Ezreal doesn't scale well with farm while most of the current toplaners do.

You can try out if it works for you but I would only recommend it if you have already mastered mid as Ezrealy since it's an ADC that has quite a high skillcap.